# Как записываются числа более 4294967295 ?

Tags: память, переменные

> В современных компьютерах под целую переменную отводится 4 байта, т.е. 32 двоичных разряда. Она может хранить числа от нуля до 2 в 32-й степени минус 1 (4294967295). 
>   http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/2193/67/lecture/1962

A как записываются числа более 4294967295 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В большинстве языков (а вероятно во всех более-менее серьезных) есть типы данных большего размера, нежели 4 байта. Обычно это 8-байтные типы данных. они позволяют представлять куда больший диапазон. К примеру тип long в C# представляет значения от  -9 223 372 036 854 775 808 до 9 223, 72 036 854 775 807. Это уже очень большой диапазон, и надо сказать, что числа , не входящие в него, могут понадобиться нечасто.  Наличие 64-битных числовых типов сейчас фактически является обязательным для языка, а потому аналогичные типы есть и в других языках. К примеру, в java это long, аналогичный шарповскому (ну или наоборот), в С++ это long long int (хотя в С++ размеры типов не заданы жестко), в Pascal это Int64. Это что касается целочисленных типов.

Кроме того существую типы с плавающей точкой. Они позволяют представлять вещественные числа, а также их диапазон может быть еще шире. По сути эти типы с лихвой покрывают 99% всех потребностей в числах (согласитесь, не каждый день программисту может потребоваться, к примеру, [такое число](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB), которое, к слову, больше, чем число атомов в известно нам вселенной).

Однако если вдруг и этих чисел будет недостаточно ( к примеру, если понадобится вычислить факториал какого-нибудь не очень большого числа), то тут на помощь может прийти так называемая длинная арифметика. Многие языки также содержат специальные типы данных для реализации очень больших чисел. О реализации такого типа в C# можно почитать [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/207754/), а вообще о самое длинной арифметике хотя бы [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: О Дитя Мечты, а где ТС писал про C#? 

@Storgt2 для C есть библиотека GMP -- длинные целые, рациональные, действительные. Хотя для длинных действительных рекомендуют пользоваться другими библиотеками.

Comment: @alexlz, ну что вы, если автор о чем-то не спрашивал, то писать об этом нельзя, даже если это пример реализации.

Comment: >О Дитя Мечты, а где ТС писал про C#?

он вообще ни про какой язык не писал (я могу ошибаться, но даже в приведенной ТСом ссылке курс не привязан к какому-либо языку). Впрочем, и в моем ответе привязки именно к шарпу не было - говоря о 8-байтовых переменных, помимо C# я привел некоторые данные и по Java и по С++ и по Pascal как наиболее известным языкам со статической типизацией. 

Что касается реализации BigInteger от майкрософта, то тут совпадение случайно - это всего лишь результат выдачи гугла по запросу "длинная арифметика" - первая же ссылка ведет на эту статью